# Getting rid of children by more complex selector string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got some code looking like this.

```
$(this)
  .children(".adjustments")
  .children(".adjustment1")
  .children(":selected")
    .html()
```

The first parts is one of the DIVs we iterate over but the others are just SPAN, SELECT and OPTION. Is that a sane way to code? If not, what'd be a recommended way to compress the statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to

```
$('.adjustments > .adjustment1 > :selected', this).html()
```

Note that if you don't specifically want to avoid deeper childs, you can get rid of the `>`.

It's rare to really have to do this, because usually you have an ID which shortens the selector, but there's no real problem here, it's not a slow selector.

Comment: Just curious, what does the `>` do in a jQuery selector?

Comment: @FastTrack its the direct children selector similar to css

Comment: @FastTrack They mean, just like in CSS, "direct children" (vs descendants).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(this).find('.ajustments .adjustments1 > :selected')
       .html();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  $(this).find(".adjustments .adjustment1 :selected").html()
```